# Koa js JOI validator is not working for post method

Tags: node.js, koa, joi, koa-router

I'm using `koa-joi-validator` in KOA js.

JOI validation works properly for `GET` method. But when `POST` method triggers it just receives the request and that's it, No validation triggered, No response sent.

GET

```
<-- GET /user/1
--> GET /user/1 200 107ms 4b
```

POST

```
<-- POST /create
```

If i remove JOI validation from POST request, then the route works fine.

app.js

```
var bodyparser = require('koa-bodyparser')

app.use(bodyparser())
```

routes.js

```
var validator = require('koa-joi-validator')

route.get('/user/:userid', validator.validate({
        type: 'json',
        params: { userid: validator.Joi.string().required() }
    }, function *() { this.body = 'test' })

route.post('/create', validator.validate({
        type: 'json',
        body: { username: validator.Joi.string().required() }
    }), function *() { this.body = 'test' })
```

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code on a very basic koa app and it just work.
If I POST without content it returns status code 400 and this body message: child "username" fails because ["username" is required].
POSTing with { "username": "John" } returns status code 200 and body: test.

Do you have an `app.on('error', ..)` to capture possible errors?

Comment: In case you are using body-parser middleware that might be what causing your code to break